# Microsoft Edge - Weird padding issue on Select

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Has any of you had a similar issue to this?

I have two selects on my page. The top one seems to be displaying some weird padding issue but I cannot see to sort it out:

[image]

Their CSS and HTML is exactly the same other than the text that is the values for them.

I have tried defining **line-height** etc but nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: Please go read [ask], and include code that makes the problem reproducible in the question; preferably in the form of a live [mcve] if possible.

Comment: Figured it out. I wrapped the option text in an if and said if it was longer than 15chars  do not display. so the really long country names were hidden and it worked. The problem seems to be when the text is long. I think it is a bug, correct?

Comment: From the screenshot you have shown I would rather assume that is was a problem with non-“western” characters, resp. the font used to display those maybe.

Comment: @cbroe I just tried a few various fonts but it didnt seem to work. It did help a little, thanks for that - never would have thought font.